# ZoL block device (zvol) exported iSCSI - LIO fails with Logical unit communication failure / read/write fail

Tags: lvm, zfs, iscsi

I have an Ubuntu (20.04.2 -5.4.0-52-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP)  storage set-up with ZoL, from which an encrypted block-device is exported via iSCSI to a different Ubuntu (18.04.5 -  4.15.0-135-generic) where it's formatted as a LVM xfs device. The set-up worked ok until a reinstall of the server was performed (as it had an issue and could not upgrade any packages) and the client had a NIC upgrade (2 x 10G - LACP). After the reinstall, it worked ok (both read and write) for about three days and then it failed.
The storage mountpoint was no longer reachable with i/o errors. I have checked the connectivity (network and iscsi) and it was ok, the iscsi session was still connected and logged in. I tried to xfs_repair, but it failed on the writing phases (5,6 and 7).
The zfs has all the devices online and performed scrub with 0 errors, checked with smartctl and no issues on any of the disks. dd works fine (both read and write), however any other type of write fails.

On the client I'm getting these error messages:

```
[  387.103390] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  387.103417] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] [descriptor]
[  387.103423] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit communication failure
[  387.103437] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 08 00 00 00 01 00 00
```

The config on the storage is as follows:

```
targetcli shell version 2.1.51
Copyright 2011-2013 by Datera, Inc and others.
For help on commands, type 'help'.

/> ls
o- / ......................................................................................................................... [...]
  o- backstores .............................................................................................................. [...]
  | o- block .................................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 1]
  | | o- name-disk ................................... [/dev/zvol/tank/dataset-name/name-iscsi (67.0TiB) write-thru activated]
  | |   o- alua ................................................................................................... [ALUA Groups: 1]
  | |     o- default_tg_pt_gp ....................................................................... [ALUA state: Active/optimized]
  | o- fileio ................................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- pscsi .................................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- ramdisk ................................................................................................ [Storage Objects: 0]
  o- iscsi ............................................................................................................ [Targets: 1]
  | o- iqn.2003-01.org.linux-iscsi.storage-name.x8664:sn.0e03591de8ee .............................................. [TPGs: 1]
  |   o- tpg1 .................................................................................................. [gen-acls, no-auth]
  |     o- acls .......................................................................................................... [ACLs: 0]
  |     o- luns .......................................................................................................... [LUNs: 1]
  |     | o- lun0 .............................. [block/name-disk (/dev/zvol/tank/dataset-name/name-iscsi) (default_tg_pt_gp)]
  |     o- portals .................................................................................................... [Portals: 1]
  |       o- 0.0.0.0:3260 ..................................................................................................... [OK]
  o- loopback ......................................................................................................... [Targets: 0]
  o- vhost ............................................................................................................ [Targets: 0]
  o- xen-pvscsi ....................................................................................................... [Targets: 0]
```

For every write command, on the storage I had a errors like these in dmesg:

```
[  316.061150] bio error: 00000000970258be,  err: 3
[  316.061153] bio error: 00000000a3caa1b4,  err: 3
[  316.061161] bio error: 00000000b8d1298b,  err: 3
[  316.061166] bio error: 000000001e0ef7b8,  err: 3
[  316.061168] bio error: 00000000a6d861a8,  err: 3
[  316.061185] bio error: 00000000a58973e3,  err: 3
[  316.061206] bio error: 00000000c05c3fc4,  err: 3
[  316.061210] bio error: 000000000ddb63f1,  err: 3
[  316.061213] bio error: 0000000060438ff5,  err: 3
[  316.061218] bio error: 00000000cd469a8e,  err: 3
[  316.061223] bio error: 000000000b873ec9,  err: 3
[  316.061227] bio error: 00000000730b5a09,  err: 3
[  316.061230] bio error: 00000000652b9a7c,  err: 3
[  316.061233] bio error: 00000000969b8d13,  err: 3
[  316.061237] bio error: 0000000079fd9679,  err: 3
```

On the client I have this version:

```
 iscsiadm --version
iscsiadm version 2.0-874
```

I have also tried exporting the iscsi target to a different client with Ubuntu 20.04 and I had the same issue, which makes me think it's coming from the storage.
I have restored the targetcli config from a save file and even reinstalled the storage and it did not help. I have been searching online for over a week now and could not find a solution.
I also discovered that I had this warning:

```
WARNING: PV /dev/PV-name in VG VG-name is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
```

So I tried:

```
$vgck --updatemetadata VG
```

which deleted the metadata from the VG but could no longer write it because of the same issue.

Other possibly unrelated checks, I had MTU=9000 on the storage, and removed it from the netplan config.

Please let me know if I missed something. Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered what was causing this. Apparently the quota was bypassed and the storage got full, I have no idea why and with what exactly. I added another zfs pool (moved the disk to a bigger chassis), removed the refreserved from the original one so I can snapshot it and zfs sent the snapshot to the new pool. After this I was able to repair the LVM and XFS metadatas and re-mounted the block device with the data.